# Does "tener el ceño fruncido" mean to have a frown?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

Is the translation of "tener el ceño fruncido" the following one: "have a frown"?

I have already learned the difference between "ceño" and "ceja".

Comment: Cornejo: as commented in your previous posts, please have a look to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers). By giving feedback to the answers you get, you will encourage them and have a better experience here.

Comment: Hello fedorqui: I am online now, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *tener el ceño fruncido* or *fruncir el ceño* is this:

[image]

It consists on showing upset through frown, that is, to move the brows (space between the eyebrows) so that its skin becomes wrinkled.

If you want to learn how to do it, wikiHow has an article on it: [Cómo fruncir el ceño](http://es.wikihow.com/fruncir-el-ce%C3%B1o).

Comment: +1 por el artículo de wikiHow, ¡qué _[pechá](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SFy6ADg)_ de reír!